# Update UIprogressView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiprogressview

I have a uiprogressview into a uicollectionview, I'm trying to update the uiprogressview after selected a cell, but it does not update, this is my code:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Storyboard.myCell, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
            let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1, repeats: true){
                (timer :Timer) in
                cell.progress.setProgress(cell.progress.progress + 0.1, animated: true)
                if cell.progress.progress >= 1 {
                    timer.invalidate()
                }
            }
            timer.fire()
    }
```

is it good?, how can I solve that problem.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here

```
collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: Storyboard.myCell, for: indexPath) as! MyCell
```

You have to use `cellForItem`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at:indexPath) as! MyCell
```

//

```
if cell.progress.progress >= 1 {
    cell.progress.progress = 0.1
}
```

Comment: This answer is correct. (voted.) Using `collectionView.dequeueReusableCell()` loads a cell that has nothing to do with the cell that's on the screen.

Comment: @DuncanC Thanks :) , yes **dequeueReusableCell** is supposed to be used inside **cellForRow** only because it loads a cell that is 100% not the clicked one where it's logic lies in fetching a cell that is  completely UN-visible Not an active visible one (The clicked)

Comment: thanks@Sh_Khan how can I do the progress indeterminate?

Comment: what do you mean by indeterminate ??

Comment: an infinite progressview like this https://raw.githubusercontent.com/GoldenOwlAsia/react-native-infinite-progress-bar/master/infinite-progress-bar.gif